# Jenkins stop a job from running on a node when a certain job is already running

Tags: jenkins, block, jobs

I have just setup auto-scaled slave nodes on Jenkins and to inject env vars, secrets and some other configurations to the slaves I am running a provisioning Jenkins job on each slave when it starts up.

However, the provisioning job can take around a minute to complete. So if a job spins up a Slave node which hasn't been provisioned it could fail. I know I could add a block when the provision job is running to EVERY job but that doesn't sound too ideal...

Is there a way that I can easily block all other jobs on the node until the provision job has finished running?

Comment: Did you heard about Parameterized Trigger Plugin? You could use it to start your downstream job only when your provision job is finished. What do you think?

Comment: I'm assuming I'd still have to apply that to every job individually. I was hoping there was an easier way of doing it.